# NFS mount Red Hat

Tags: linux, redhat, shared, nfs, fstab

I am trying to share a folder between two machines.
In the A machine I created a folder with 666 permission, in /etc/exports add an entry with `<A machine folder> <B hostname>(ro,sync)` and restart service nfs-server.

In the B machine I create a folder with 666 permission, add an entry in /etc/fstab with `<A hostname><A path folder> <B path folder> nfs ro,sync 0 0`

When I execute `mount -a` to force the mount in B machine, it shows that the directory is mounted correctly (with "mount" command I can check it) but when I try go inside the folder "Permission denied" appears. I only can fix this message giving execution permission (665) to the folder located in the A machine.

I have tried with many combinations for this purpose.

I wouldn't like to give execution permision to the folder located in the A machine.

Any ideas?

Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to /etc/exports "no_root_squash"